# C# Call a method from a different form class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, methods

Ok, so I have a method in one class and I'm trying to call it from another class.

Form1:

```
    public void ChangeBack(Color clr)
    {
        this.BackColor = clr;
    }
```

Form2:

```
    public void ChangBackColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ColorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Form1.ChangeBack(ColorDialog.Color);
        }
    }
```

But I need to make the ChangeBack method static to be able to call it. So:

Form1:

```
    public static void ChangeBack(Color clr)
    {
        this.BackColor = clr;
    }
```

But then I can't use "this." as the void doesn't allow it because it's static. And I can't create a new form1 because it needs to run overall in two windows.

Please help!C

Comment: Which one is the main form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with multiple forms, you need to pass a reference to the second form, so that it "knows" about the first form. To do this you will need to change the constructor of your second form, and add a private reference to that form, like so:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    //Variables
    private Form1 _ParentForm; //Add this here

    //Constructor
    public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
    {
        InitalizeComponent();
        _ParentForm = parentForm; //Add this here
    }
}
```

The, when you create the second form on your main form, you can use `this` to pass the reference of itself on to the new form:

```
class Form1 : Form
{

    public void ChangeBack(Color clr) //No longer needs to be static
    {
        this.BackColor = clr;
    }

    public void CreateSecondForm()
    {
        Form2 secondForm = new Form2(this);
        secondForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Then you can call any function on the parent form (i.e. Form1) from the second form like so:

```
public void ChangBackColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ColorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Access Form1's reference with _ParentForm instead of Form1
        _ParentForm.ChangeBack(ColorDialog.Color);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you said and in the colorDialog part has an error. It says under "_ParentForm.ChangeBack(ColorDialog.Color)" that **"Form doesn't contain a definition for "ChangeBack"**

Comment: @NumNumDude okay, I've fixed that issue, change the `Form2` class to have `_ParentForm` as a `Form1` instead of just `Form` and change the constructor of `Form2` to the same.

Comment: Just a supporting note here for anyone else that comes across this - make sure the method/functions protection level is set to "public" as a private one will render it inaccessible to the second form.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with 2 different WinForm windows you should simply pass a reference from one window to the other (typically using constructor). For instance:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm(this); // where this is your main WinForm
```

after that you can use the reference to the main WinForm to call it's methods.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you cannot make the method static and access instance of the object.

Change `BackColor` to a static property or change your method to a non static one